# How to stop character falling of the screen in sprite kit?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm using this to stop it falling off the bottom, but I want the character to be able to walk off of the side of the screen.

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

Comment: Did you look at `bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:toPoint:`?

Comment: yes but i don't understand how to use it?

Comment: Can you try add self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

Comment: What about removing the player when he reaches a certain point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGFloat enlargeByPoints = 100.0;
CGRect frame = self.frame;
frame.origin.x -= enlargeByPoints;
frame.size.width += enlargeByPoints * 2.0;
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:frame];
```

This expands the size of the edge loop by 100 points on both sides of the screen.

The player will still run into an invisible wall after leaving the screen though. But you can use CGRectContainsRect or other tests to determine whether a node has left the screen entirely, and then remove it or perhaps position it at the other side of the screen.